# How to use positional argument with embed quotes in bash?

Tags: json, bash, jq, positional-parameter

I'm trying to create a bash script that automates configuration of some letsencrypt related stuff.

The file that I have to edit is json so I would just use `jq` to edit it and pass the site name to it from the positional arguments of the script, but I can't get the positional argument passed into the json text.

I'm trying to do domething like the following:

```
JSON=`jq '. + { "ssl_certificate": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$2/fullchain.pem" }' <<< echo site_config.json`
JSON=`jq '. + { "ssl_certificate_key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$2/fullchain.pem" }' <<< ${JSON}`
echo -e "$JSON" > site_config.json
```

Where the second positional argument (`$2`) contain the domain name required to be set in the json file.

How this can be done?

Original json:

```
{
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2"
}
```

Wanted json:

```
{
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "ssl_certificate": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.com/fullchain.pem",
  "ssl_certificate_key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.com/fullchain.pem"
}
```

Comment: As first step I suggest to remove in first row: `<<< echo`

Comment: Add site_config.json to your question and your desired output (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. String construction under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

I use `printf` and *octal* representation for nesting quotes and double quotes:

```
printf -v JSON 'Some "double quoted: \047%s\047"' "Any string"
echo "$JSON"
Some "double quoted: 'Any string'"
```

### 2. Using `jq`, strictly answer to edited question:

```
myFunc() {
    local file="$1" site="$2" JSON
    printf -v JSON '. + {
        "ssl_certificate": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/%s/fullchain.pem",
        "ssl_certificate_key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/%s/fullchain.pem"
    }' "$site" "$site"
    jq "$JSON" <"$file"
}
```

Then run:

```
myFunc site_config.json test.com
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "ssl_certificate": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem",
  "ssl_certificate_key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem"
}

myFunc site_config.json test.com >site_config.temp && mv site_config.{temp,conf}
```

Or even:

```
myFunc <(
    printf '{ "key1":"value1","key2":"value2","comment":"Let\047s doit\041"  }'
    ) test.com
```

Will render:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "comment": "Let's doit!",
  "ssl_certificate": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem",
  "ssl_certificate_key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem"
}
```

#### 2b. Better written with `jq`'s `--arg` option:

Thanks to [peak's detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64569181/1765658)!

I use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arrays to store strings with quotes, spaces and other special characters. This is more readable as there is no need to escape end-of-line (backslashes) and permit comments:

```
myFunc() {
    local file="$1" site="$2"
    local JSON=(
        --arg ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$site/fullchain.pem"
        --arg ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$site/fullchain.pem"
        '. + {$ssl_certificate, $ssl_certificate_key}' # this syntax
        # do offer two advantages: 1: no backslashes and 2: permit comments.
    )
    jq "${JSON[@]}" <"$file"
}
```

### 3. Inline edit function

For editing a small script. I prefer to use `cp -a` in order to preserve
attributes and ensure a valid operation before replacement.

If you plan to use this, mostly for replacing, you could add replacement in your function:

```
myFunc() {
    local REPLACE=false
    [ "$1" = "-r" ] && REPLACE=true && shift
    local file="$1" site="$2"
    local JSON=( --arg ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$site/fullchain.pem"
        --arg ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$site/fullchain.pem"
        '. + {$ssl_certificate, $ssl_certificate_key}' )
    if $REPLACE;then
        cp -a "$file" "${file}.temp"
        exec {out}>"${file}.temp"
    else
        exec {out}>&1
    fi
    jq "${JSON[@]}" <"$file" >&$out &&
        $REPLACE && mv "${file}.temp" "$file"
    exec {out}>&-
}
```

Then to modify file instead of dumping result to terminal, you have to add `-r` option:

```
myFunc -r site_config.json test.org
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot get the positional argument passed into the json text.

In general, by far the best way to do that is to use jq's --arg and/or --argjson command-line options.  This is safe, and in the present case means that you would only have to call jq once.  E.g.:

```
< site_config.json \
jq --arg sslc "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$2/fullchain.pem" \
   --arg sslck "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$2/fullchain.pem" '
   . + {ssl_certificate: $sslc, ssl_certificate_key: $sslck }'
```

Once you're sure things are working properly, feel free to use moreutils's `sponge` :-)

### A DRY-er solution

Thanks to a neat convenience feature of jq, one can write more DRY-ly:

```
< site_config.json \
jq --arg ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$2/fullchain.pem" \
   --arg ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$2/fullchain.pem" '
   . + {$ssl_certificate, $ssl_certificate_key }'
``
```

Comment: I don't use morutils. for this, I often use: `file=site_config.json;jq "${JSON[@]}" < $file | diff -u $file - | tee >(patch -p0) | grep ^+` . This modify file and show new lines.